# How to Deal with Textual Data?

Tags: r

In `R`, you have a certain data frame with textual data, e.g. the second column has words instead of numbers. How can you remove the rows of the data frame with a certain word (e.g. "total") in the second column? `data <- data[-(data[,2] == "total"),]` does not work for me.

Besides, is there an easy way to convert these words sequentially into numbers? (I.e., first word becomes 1, second appeared word becomes 2, and so on.) I would rather not use a loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `!` to negate. For the sequence, use either `seq_along` or `as.numeric(factor(.))` depending on what you are actually looking for.

Here's some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(V1 = 1:15, V2 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, TRUE))
mydf
#    V1 V2
# 1   1  A
# 2   2  B
# 3   3  B
# 4   4  C
# 5   5  A
# 6   6  C
# 7   7  C
# 8   8  B
# 9   9  B
# 10 10  A
# 11 11  A
# 12 12  A
# 13 13  C
# 14 14  B
# 15 15  C
```

Let's remove any rows where there is an "A" in column "V2":

```
mydf2 <- mydf[!mydf$V2 == "A", ]
mydf2
#    V1 V2
# 2   2  B
# 3   3  B
# 4   4  C
# 6   6  C
# 7   7  C
# 8   8  B
# 9   9  B
# 13 13  C
# 14 14  B
# 15 15  C
```

Now, let's create two new columns. The first sequentially counts each occurrence of each "word" in column "V2". The second converts each unique "word" into a number.

```
mydf2$Seq <- ave(as.character(mydf2$V2), mydf2$V2, FUN = seq_along)
mydf2$WordAsNum <- as.numeric(factor(mydf2$V2))
mydf2
#    V1 V2 Seq WordAsNum
# 2   2  B   1         1
# 3   3  B   2         1
# 4   4  C   1         2
# 6   6  C   2         2
# 7   7  C   3         2
# 8   8  B   3         1
# 9   9  B   4         1
# 13 13  C   4         2
# 14 14  B   5         1
# 15 15  C   5         2
```

Comment: @Pippo, no problem. You should also know that to drop more than one "word" you will need to use `%in%` instead of `==`, and to drop partial matches (for example, to match either "tot" or "total"), you should explore `grepl`.